# using std::vector / std::array for small std::set

Tags: c++, vector, stl, network-programming

I am doing server software with `poll()` / `epoll()`. Server usually will listen on single port. However some user might decide the server to listen on 2-3 or more ports.

Trivial example is IP4 localhost, IP6 localhost and domain socket.

For this I need to keep the `file descriptors` in some array like structure. For just 2-3 `file descriptors`, shall I use simple `std::vector<int>` or shall I use some heavy artillery data structure such `std::set`?

## Edit:

`poll()` / `epoll()` returns one or more `file descriptor`, e.g. `int`.

I need to understand if this is server fd or client fd.

In case there is only one server fd, this is simple if inside event loop:

```
if (fd_from_poll == server_fd){
    // accept new clients
}else{
    // serve already connected client.
}
```

For clients I have `std::map<int,ClientData>`.

However I do not think is wize to assume if `file descriptor` is not a client then it is a server. I want to keep all server `file descriptors` somewhere, so I can `close` them and so on. I do not need to have any information than this `int`, so I can use `std::vector<int>` or `std::set<int>` or `std::unordered_set<int>`.

Once again, in usual case there will be only one or two `file descriptors` in this container.

Comment: May I have comment on downvotes?

Comment: For a server system you need to adjust the order of executions based on their priority, the task of utmost priority should be handled first, hence `std::priority_queue` would be the cat's whiskers. Also, I would suggest you clarify your motivations more specifically, since `vector` and `set` both has their pros and cons and no one can make a reasonable judgement without any knowledge about your specific requirements.

Comment: It shouldn't really matter, since you're not constantly opening and closing ports. Rather, you open the port once, and then you obtain a handle to it directly from your epoll loop.

Comment: @KerrekSB - sure, however, when `file descriptor` come from `poll()` (there is no user data ptr there), I need to lookup it and see if this is server fd or this is some client. For the clients I already use `std::map` with all connection data inside (partially read buffer etc). There is a way I can assume, if it is not found in the client map, so is server - but this is bit stupid simplification.

Answer (score 0):

I read related posts for `std::map` vs `std::vector<std::pair<K,V> >` and decided to use `std::vector` along with `std::find`.

I do not even sort the vector, because binary search is slower if there are less that 6-7 elements.

I never posted the code with single integer, but now the code looks like this:

```
template<class SELECTOR, class WORKER, class CLIENTBUFFER>
bool AsyncLoop<SELECTOR, WORKER, CLIENTBUFFER>::isServerFD_(int const fd){
    return std::find(serverFD_.cbegin(), serverFD_.cend(), fd) != serverFD_.cend();
}

template<class SELECTOR, class WORKER, class CLIENTBUFFER>
void AsyncLoop<SELECTOR, WORKER, CLIENTBUFFER>::handleRead_(int const fd){
    if ( isServerFD_(fd) ){ // <= changed from if (fd == serverFD)
        while (handleConnect_(fd));
        return;
    }
    // ...
    // serve clients...
```